# Probability and combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many 3-letter words with or without meaning, can be formed out of the letters of the word, 'LOGARITHMS', if repetition of letters is not allowed?
Answer for this is $^{10} P_3 $. 
 What is answer if the repetiton is allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

Without repetition as you state, you have, $V_{m,n} = V_{10,3} = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!} = \frac{10!}{7!} = 720$ words.

If repetition is allowed then you have $V_{R}^{m,n} = V^{10,3} = 10^{3} = 1000$ words of 3 letters each.